# Query for location returns nearest values on limit instead of order

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a class called Shouts. Each shout has a property "location" which stores the location of this Shout.

Each user has a property called `radius`, which is an integer, and a property called location, which is the user's current location.

I try to use `PFQueryTableViewController` to query for all the Shouts within `radius` kilometers around the user's location. The User is a custom subclass using PFSubClassing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    MyUser *currentUser = [MyUser currentUser];
    [query orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
    [query setLimit:10];
    [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:currentUser.location withinKilometers:currentUser.radius];

    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }
    return query;
}
```

This works fine as long as there are less than 10 Shouts present. However, as soon as the amount of results is larger than the limit, the query returns the results nearest to the user's location, not the first 10 results with the newest updatedAt value, which I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong, or did I uncover some kind of bug?

Comment: Sounds like you found a bug, report it here: https://parse.com/help

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a known bug in parse, here's a workaround that I implemented to address this issue:

This bug does not apply to `whereKey:withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:toNortheast:` . So, we want to create a bounding box around the circle in which we want to search. We'll do it this way (taken from another SO question)

CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentUser.location.latitude, currentUser.location.longitude);

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerCoord, 2*currentUser.radius*1000 , 2*currentUser.radius*1000);

double latMin = region.center.latitude - .5 * region.span.latitudeDelta;
double latMax = region.center.latitude + .5 * region.span.latitudeDelta;
double lonMin = region.center.longitude - .5 * region.span.longitudeDelta;
double lonMax = region.center.longitude + .5 * region.span.longitudeDelta;

PFGeoPoint *southwest = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:latMin longitude:lonMin];
PFGeoPoint *northeast = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:latMax longitude:lonMax];
```

Now, we can use the other method to retrieve the data. However, we only want data from within a circle around the user, not a box - so this returns too many results (and also, it may have problems around the poles, keep that in mind)

To overcome this, we iterate through self.objects in `objectsDidLoad:` and remove every object that is too far away.

However, we cannot overwrite `self.objects`. Thus, we create another property called `self.validObjects`, which we will use to store the actual values. To get this working, we also overwrite the following two methods (here shown for my simple case with just one section):

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.validObjects.count;
}
- (PFObject*) objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return self.validObjects[indexPath.row];
}
```

That's it!